# How trigge stm32 one pulse mode timer internally

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f1

I've used the stm32 one pule mode timer to generate pulse train. one pulse mode generate the pulse train in response of a extranl event originally, but i want to know that is there anyway to trigger the OPM timer internally? for example by writing a bit to a specific register.

Comment: The first case is actualy more complex, then the question. To start timer by some external event you have to configure it in slave mode. For a software trigger, just don't use slave mode, and timer will start once CEN bit is set.

Comment: You have to explain what "internally" means in this context. What "external" is then. Yes, you can enable one pulse mode by setting a special OPM bit in timer control register. And you can start counter by writing to another specific Counter Enable bit in timer.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a considerable time to figure this out. I had the same requirement.

**Here's the HAL-generated setup for TIM4:**

```
static void MX_TIM4_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 1 */
  htim4.Instance = TIM4;
  htim4.Init.Prescaler = 8399;
  htim4.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim4.Init.Period = 1000;
  htim4.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim4.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim4, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_Init(&htim4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_OnePulse_Init(&htim4, TIM_OPMODE_SINGLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim4, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_ACTIVE;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 1000;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_OC_ConfigChannel(&htim4, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_OC_Start_IT(&htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_Init 2 */
  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim4);

}
```

Now, in order to re-trigger the timer again to generate another pulse, you do the following:

```
TIM4->ARR = 1200;
TIM4->CCMR1 = 0b1100000;
TIM4->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
```

This allows you to generate a pulse on an OC channel and then re-trigger the timer to generate another pulse at will.